# how do I use nested-loops to print elements of an array that when added together form the sum of the same array?

Tags: java, arrays, nested-loops, bluej, sub-array

This the test method that I'm using to check if my method works correctly. I know that I must use nested loops but not sure about the implementation of them.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Task 1
        int[] array1 = {4, 5, 7, 5, 5, -10};
        System.out.print("Task 1: [");

        // should print [ 4, 5, 7 ]
        for (Integer i : subarray(array1)) {
            System.out.print(" ");
            System.out.print(i);
        }

        System.out.println(" ]");
        
        // should print [ 2 1 1 ]
        int[] array2 = {-6, 2, 1, 1, 5, 3, -2};
        System.out.print("Task 1: [ ");

        for (Integer i : subarray(array2)) {
            System.out.print(" ");
            System.out.print(i);
        }
```

This the method I have written up so far.

```
public static int[] subarray(int[] original) {
    int result = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < original.length; i++) {
        result+=original[i];
    }
    return original;
}
```

Comment: Before writing code to do this you should figure out how to do it on paper.  Did you do that? If so, how did you solve it manually?  If not, sit down with pencil and paper and solve the problem for your arrays.

Comment: What if there are multiple subarrays that could fit the condition, do we have to print all of them, the smallest one, or the largest one? Please specify.